# adding button in a row in kendo grid

Tags: grails

I am using Kendo grid in my grails application and my requirement is that with every row, one button should also get displayed and on clicking that button, one new row get inserted with the same value as of top row.please can any one help.

thanks

Comment: +1 for pointing me to discover KendoUI - awesome.  Sorry I can't answer your issue!

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved using custom templates.
For example:

```
$("#myGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id"
            }
        }
    },
    columns: [
        {field: 'some_field', title: 'some title'},
        {field: '', title: '', template: '<a href="\\#" onclick="duplicateRow(#=id#); rertun false;">duplicate row</a>'}
    ]
});
```

Note that this example assumes every object in your grid has a unique field called "id".

An example duplicateRow method:

```
function duplicateRow(id) {
    var selectedItem = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.get(id);
    var newItem = createNewItem(selectedItem);
    $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.add(newItem);
}
```

Note that you have to write createNewItem function which should create a copy from the selectedItem with a new id. The position where the new item will be inserted depends on the sort you are using in your grid.